# Only update mongo document if value is bigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I got a collection of documents in mongo DB. 
One of the fields in the document is "verison" : int

I was wondering if there is a practical way to use this value to prevent update of the document when there is an attempt to update it with the same or smaller version number.

example : 
my collection has a document :

```
{
"name": "john",
"version": 3
}
```

if I try to send update with :

```
{
"name": "rick"
"version": 3
}
```

It wont update it, and I will get an indication that there was no update so I can handle this in some way in my code.

I am using node.js with native mongo DB driver.

Comment: So all you need is if version number is 4 then it should update else it should skip thats all right?

Comment: pretty much yes

Comment: then normal update command will do db.collection.update({version: {$gt:3}},{$set: {name:'rick'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve using the below Code.

```
db.collection.update({'version':{$gte : 3}},{$set : {name:'Abc'}},{upsert : true,new:true})
```